# Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Pessoal estou com um problema em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo no Android Studio, ele possui a opção para inserir uma *activity* (Navigation Drawer Activity)
entao a inseri e coloquei um botão para chama-la.

O Problema é que quando clico no botão a aplicação se encerra. Quando crio uma aplicação desse tipo (Navigation Drawer Activity) funciona perfeitamente mas não estou conseguindo chama-la em meu projeto já criado.

Dei o nome de `MenuActivity` e quero passar do login para ela ao clicar no botão.

O método que chama a *Activity*:

```
public void click_chamaMenu(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

logcat Error:

```
02-04 15:10:52.814  21392-21392/com.example.celsoribeiro.titanapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.celsoribeiro.titanapp, PID: 21392
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.celsoribeiro.titanapp/com.example.celsoribeiro.titanapp.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.example.celsoribeiro.titanapp.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

----------
```

Comment: Qual o logcat ao encerrar? Mostre o código onde o erro ocorre.

Comment: Não aparece erro algum, da build sucessfull mas a aplicação é encerrada.

Comment: O fato da aplicação não ter erros ao compilar não quer dizer que não os tenha ao executar. Ao encerrar é mostrada alguma mensagem?

Comment: Navigation Drawer não é um Fragmento? bom se for uma `Activity` mesmo, então, o problema pode ser que vc não inseriu no `manifest.xml`. Ou então pelo que vi vc não criou o listener. E sim colocou a chamada no XML na instrução `onClick`, verifique o nome do método em java se é o mesmo no xml.

Comment: Ao encerrar a aplicaçao aparece só a mensagem : "O Titan App parou."

Comment: É uma activity sim porem possui a classe NavigationDrawerFragment que é um fragmento, mas eu inseri no manifest sim.

Comment: Se aparece a mensagem *"O Titan App parou."* então, se você estiver a correr a aplicação no Android Studio, o erro será apresentado no logcat. Edite a sua pergunta e coloque-o-lá.

Comment: Creio que consegui resolver aqui , a linha que diz : You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. Faltou colocar o tema da activity no manifest, assim que coloquei consegui o que eu queria. Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram.

Answer (score 1):

A razão de estar dando erro na compilação é justamente porque você está trabalhando com uma classe que estende `ActionBarActivity` (Deprecated nas novas versões) ao invés de `AppCompatActivity`.

Linha do erro:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.celsoribeiro.titanapp/com.example.celsoribeiro.titanapp.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Tente inserir `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`, e garanta que o style utilizado seja compatível com o AppCompat.

Uma dica de amigo que lhe dou é utilizar o [Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) ao invés do Navigation Drawer do Android Studio, ele é bem mais sofisticado e costuma dar menos trabalho.